# Calling function from dynamic library?

Tags: c, linux, dynamic-library

I'm experimenting with using dynamic libraries and C on Linux. The following code will print wrong ouput:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

int main(int argc, char **arg)
{
        void *dl = dlopen("./lib.so", RTLD_NOW);
        if (!dl) {
                fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: %s\n", dlerror());
                exit(1);
        }

        char *ver = dlsym(dl, "show_version");
        printf("%s\n", ver);
}
```

If I make the following change the output will be correct:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

int main(int argc, char **arg)
{
        void *dl = dlopen("./lib.so", RTLD_NOW);
        if (!dl) {
                fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: %s\n", dlerror());
                exit(1);
        }

        char *(*ver)() = dlsym(dl, "show_version");
        printf("%s\n", ver());
}
```

I'm not sure what `char *(*ver)()` is doing and why it's needed? Can anyone explain?

Comment: `show_version` is a name of a function. `ver` is a pointer to a function. `char *(*ver)()` is a declaration of a pointer to a function unlike `char *ver` - which is a pointer to `char`

Comment: In other words, `dlsym(dl, "show_version");` does not run the `show_version` function and return the result. Instead, it returns a pointer to the function itself. To run the function and get the version string, you have to invoke the function via the function pointer like you do in your second example.

Comment: Using typedefs makes things much more readable. It may be useful to use `typeof()` to generate the typedef, if you have access to a declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dlsym` - *obtain address of a symbol in a shared object or executable*

This means that when you do `dlsym(dl, "show_version");` you are not actually calling the function `show_version` in your shared library. You obtain *the address* of that function - which can be used to call the function over and over again.

To "decode" what `char *(*ver)()` means, you can use what is often called the [Clockwise/Spiral Rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html)

```
        +-----+
        |     V
char*  (*ver) ()   ver is a 
 ^      ^ |   |    pointer to
 |      | |   |    a function (taking no arguments)
 |      +-+   |    returning char*
 |            |
 +------------+
```

I assume the above matches the signature of the `show_version` function that you put in the shared library. Example:

```cpp
// a function (taking no arguments), returning a char*
char *show_version(void) {
    static char version[] = "1.0";
    return version;
}
```

Using the same rule on your first attempt, `char* ver`:

```
char* ver
  ^    |     ver is a
  |    |     char*
  +----+
```

You need a pointer to a function (with the correct signature) to be able to call the function and get the result you want. You can't call a `char*` and when you do  `printf("%s\n", ver);` it'll just start reading the memory at the address (where your function is stored) until it finds a null terminator. You probably see just gibberish.

If you on the other hand have a proper function pointer, you can as you've noticed, call the function it points at with `ver()` and you get a `char*` in return which points at the string your dynamically loaded function returned.

You can also use function pointers in your programs without involving shared libraries.

```
#include <stdio.h>

long foo(short x, int y) {
    return x + y;
}

int main() {
    long(*foo_ptr)(short, int) = foo;

    // foo_ptr is a pointer to a function taking (short, int) as
    // arguments and returning a long

    printf("%ld\n", foo(1, 2) );       // prints 3
    printf("%ld\n", foo_ptr(1, 2) );   // also prints 3
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`dlsym(dl, "show_version")` returns the address for the symbol `show_version`. Since `show_version` is a function, that is the address of the function.

`char *ver = dlsym(…);` puts that pointer in a `char *`, which is basically useless. The pointer to a function does not point to bytes that are useful to print. Then `printf("%s\n", ver);` says to print the bytes that `ver` points to as if they were a string. But the bytes there are (in a typical C implementation) machine code for the function. They are not the bytes of a character string you want to print.

`char *(*ver)() = dlsym(…);` defines `ver` to be a pointer to a function whose arguments are not specified and that returns a `char *`. To see this:

- `char something` declares `something` to be a `char`.
- `char *something` declares `something` to be a pointer to a `char`.
- `char *something()` declares `something` to be a function whose arguments are not specified that returns a pointer to `char`.
- `char *(*something)()` declares `something` to a pointer to such a function.

Then, in `printf("%s\n", ver());`, `ver()` calls this function. The `char *` it returns is passed to `printf` to be printed.

Comment: This reads as though `dlsym` can only be used to locate functions. It returns the address of whatever `show_version` happens to be. If `show_version` were a pointer to the first byte of a string (with a very odd name) then the first code would work.

Comment: @rici: Right, updated.